# Matching multiple values from array to object array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, react-native, filter

I am trying to create a booking app and mark out the slots unavailable. The slots unavailable are in an array for example:

```
const unavailable = [ "11:00am a 12:00pm", "17:00pm a 18:00pm"]
```

and the total slots are

```
 let slots = [ {
    slot: "9:00am a 10:00am",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  {
    slot: "10:00am a 11:00am",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  { slot: "11:00am a 12:00pm", isReserved: false },
  {
    slot: "15:00pm a 16:00pm",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  {
    slot: "17:00pm a 18:00pm",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  {
    slot: "18:00pm a 19:00pm",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  { slot: "19:00pm a 20:00pm", isReserved: false },
];
```

my goal is to use the unavailable array and each value inside and find how to change that field  to

```
isReserved: true
```

I've tried to filter like so

```
    const matches = slots.filter((same) => same.slot === unavailable);
```

but does not work. What did kind of work was

```
    const matches = slots.filter((same) => same.slot === unavailable[0]);
```

but that only matches the first value, and I still do not know how to change the isReserved field.

Comment: do you want a new array or mutate the old one?

Comment: i would like to mutate, but either or should work for what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate and update if a slot is found.

```js
const
    unavailable = ["11:00am a 12:00pm", "17:00pm a 18:00pm"],
    slots = [{ slot: "9:00am a 10:00am", isReserved: false }, { slot: "10:00am a 11:00am", isReserved: false }, { slot: "11:00am a 12:00pm", isReserved: false }, { slot: "15:00pm a 16:00pm", isReserved: false }, { slot: "17:00pm a 18:00pm", isReserved: false }, { slot: "18:00pm a 19:00pm", isReserved: false }, { slot: "19:00pm a 20:00pm", isReserved: false }];

slots.forEach(o => {
    if (unavailable.some(slot => slot === o.slot)) o.isReserved = true;
});

console.log(slots);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you like not to mutate the original array, you could map the objects with a new property.

```js
const
    unavailable = ["11:00am a 12:00pm", "17:00pm a 18:00pm"],
    slots = [{ slot: "9:00am a 10:00am", isReserved: false }, { slot: "10:00am a 11:00am", isReserved: false }, { slot: "11:00am a 12:00pm", isReserved: false }, { slot: "15:00pm a 16:00pm", isReserved: false }, { slot: "17:00pm a 18:00pm", isReserved: false }, { slot: "18:00pm a 19:00pm", isReserved: false }, { slot: "19:00pm a 20:00pm", isReserved: false }],
    result = slots.map(o => ({
        ...o,
        isReserved: o.isReserved || unavailable.some(slot => slot === o.slot)
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: the second option you have provided worked perfectly! saved me so much time thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

you can use the map operator and can achieve this.

```js
const unavailable = [ "11:00am a 12:00pm", "17:00pm a 18:00pm"]
let slots = [ {
    slot: "9:00am a 10:00am",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  {
    slot: "10:00am a 11:00am",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  { slot: "11:00am a 12:00pm", isReserved: false },
  {
    slot: "15:00pm a 16:00pm",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  {
    slot: "17:00pm a 18:00pm",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  {
    slot: "18:00pm a 19:00pm",
    isReserved: false,
  },
  { slot: "19:00pm a 20:00pm", isReserved: false },
];

const slots = slots.map(slotobj=>{
if(unavailable.includes(slotobj.slot)){
 slotobj.isReserved =true
}
return slotobj;
})
```